# setResizable() not working properly

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I tested this example to create dialog which cannot be resized with mouse drag:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.setPadding(new Insets(10, 50, 50, 50));
    Scene scene = new Scene(bp);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
```

To my surprise I can drag the main stage with the mouse, is this a bug or I'm missing some code? I use Centos 6 and JVM 7_21 64-bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizablity and Draggablity are 2 different characteristics. The window in your example is not resizable due to the line

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

But it still draggable. To prevent draggablity you can use

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

or

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

Comment: Yes, but the default window frame is removed. How I can preserve the default window frame?

Comment: @PeterPenzov. The default decorated window frame is platform depended (and specific) and managed by the OS. To preserve it, I think you need to do much more platform dependent hack there. Instead when the decoration is transparent, provide your own stylish window frame with its fancy "max, min, close" buttons.